# Is there any approach of shared mutex for a short shared-operations and few unique operations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, mutex

As known `std::shared_timed_mutex` (C++14) and `std::shared_mutex` (C++17) has a performance advantage over `std::mutex` **only for a very long** `std::shared_lock`s (reads-operations), and when `std::shared_lock`s  more than `std::unique_lock`s.

But even if most of its are read operations, and they are short, then `std::mutex` will be faster - that is why in the C++11 standard `std::shared_mutex` and `std::shared_timed_mutex` were not included immediately.

Is there any approach or implementation of some kind of shared mutex, which has a performance advantage over `std::mutex`, also **for a short operations**, if the reads are not just more, and a lot more as below?

`std::unique_lock` / `std::shared_lock` = 1 / 1 000 000 000 000

Is there any approach of shared mutex for a short shared-operations and few unique operations?

Comment: ive wrote my own simple `shared spin-lock` a while ago, maybe it is faster (idk) https://github.com/domso/network/blob/master/network/rw_mutex.h https://github.com/domso/network/blob/master/src/rw_mutex.cpp

Answer (score 0):

a possible approach could be the usage of duplicated data. this should scale very well with a high number of readers and only a few writers. I dont know if its faster than `shared_mutex()`, but is an alternative

Basic Idea:

Every reader works on a reader-copy, while a writer can modify the seperate writer-copy. To commit changes you store the writer-object in a new reader-object, which will be acquired from every new reader. The next commit would be stored into the now old reader-object. Therefor the writer needs to wait, until all old readers released their lock on this object.

simple example:

```
struct data{
    int a;
};

struct secured_data {
    data read[2];
    data write;
    std::atomic<int> current = 0;
    std::atomic<int> num_read[2] = 0;

    std::mutex m;

    data* read_lock() {
        // increase reader-counter of current data-object
        int c = current.load();
        num_read[c].fetch_add(1);
        // return current copy
        return &read + c;
    }

    void read_unlock(data* old) {
        // decrease the old data-object (which was returned by read_lock())
        num_read[old - &read].fetch_sub(1);


    }

    data* lock() {
        m.lock();
        // every modification happens on a seperate copy
        write = read[current.load()];
        return &write;
    }

    void unlock() {
       int c;
       // wait until all readers using an old copy have released their lock
       do {
           c = current.load();
       } while (num_read[(c + 1) % 2].load() != 0);
       // copy into new read-object
       read[(c + 1) % 2] = write;
       // swap read-object
       // all readers now use an old version
       current.store((c + 1) % 2);
       m.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thak you. But: `num_read[c].fetch_add(1);` is Read-Modify-Write-operation, which plays a cache line in Ping Pong, i.e. eXclusive state of cache-line which contains `num_read[c]` transmitted to each CPU-Core for each `read_lock()` or `read_unlock()` - it is the same that happens in the conventional `std::mutex` and it can't be faster than `std::mutex`. When there are only readers (without writers), then shared-lock can use only `load(any barrier)` and `store(std::memory_order_release)` to be faster than `std::mutex`.